# How to select column names using a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I am very new to lambda expressions.

I have this xml

```
<Booksshel>
   <BookN>
       <column>author</column>
       <column>Price</column>
       <column>Date</column>
   </BookN>
   <BookDetails id=1>
       <author>john</author>
       <price>50</price>
   </BookDetails>
   <BookDetails id=2>
       <author>kalam</author>
       <price>90</price>
   </BookDetails>
   <BookDetails id=3>
       <author>sachin</author>
       <price>70</price>
       <Date>12-08-2015</Date>
   </BookDetails>
</Booksshel>
```

In the above XML I have column names in a list 'author, price' that I need to select the particular `BookDetails` using a lambda expression.

```
foreach (var col in columnName)
{
    sl.AddRange(_doc.Descendants("BookDetails")
          .Where(p =>Id.Contains(p.Element("BookDetails").Value))
          .Select(p=> New { p.Element(col).Value }).ToList())
}
```

This is raising some strange issues. How can I get the details?

Comment: Raising *which* strange issues?

Comment: You will get syntax error for foreach (in columnName), it would be foreach (var col in columnName)

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`[System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'.

Comment: yes exactly i forgot sorry and thanks for reply @Rob

Comment: still i am getting error

Comment: what output are you expecting ?

Comment: @Sadda-shutu You still haven't actually told us what errors you're getting.

Comment: You should focus on this part of the code: `New { p.Element(col).Value }` That should be just an expression that returns a string. Probably you just need `p.Element(col).Value` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you "need to select the particular BookDetails using a lambda expression" you can select the bookdetails for a specific book likfe this:

```
var result = _doc.Descendants("BookDetails")
                 .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == "1")
                 .Select(b => new { Author = b.Element("author").Value, Price = b.Element("price").Value });
```

and you can loop through the results like this

```
foreach (var book1 in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{book1.Author}\t\t{book1.Price}");
}
```

or since you are expceting one result you can get the item like this:

```
var book2 = result.FirstOrDefault();
if (book2 != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{book2.Author}\t\t{book2.Price}");
}
```

Comment: yes thank you very much @Volkan pakson really you saved my day

Answer (score -1):

```
var tableColumns = (from t in typeof(TableModel).GetProperties()
                          select t.Name).ToList();

 
foreach (var column in tableColumns)
{
    var col = _context.Table.Select(s =>  s.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(s)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This is not related to the question. Where's the XML here? Apart from that, it's a code-only answer. When posting code, a bit of explanation is welcome.